# How should a server respond when the client side socket calls Disconnect method?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I'm very new to networking. I'm making a winform TCP socket chat program using C#. Everything is fine but I'm struggling to accept disconnection. I think that I have some misundersting of handling disconnection.

I added a disconnecting functionality (to learn how to use Disconnect method in Socket) in the client program but I have a problem with it. **When I clicked disconnect button in the client program, it calls the Socket's DisconnectAsync() method**:

```
public async void Disconnect()
{
    tokenSource.Cancel(); // Cancel asynchronous loop code waiting message
    await sock.DisconnectAsync(true); // Here throws an exception!
    sock.Close();
    streamReader.Close();
    streamWriter.Close();
}
```

**And the server program receive 0byte packet and also try to disconnect the client by calling this method**:

```
public async void RemoveClient(ClientHandler client)
{
    client.tokenSource.Cancel(); // Cancel asynchronous loop code waiting message
    await client.sock.DisconnectAsync(false);
    client.sock.Close();
    client.streamReader.Close();
    client.streamWriter.Close();
    clients.Remove(client);
}
```

However, after that, the client program throws an exception - *system.net.sockets.socketexception: disconnect A request to send or receive data was not allowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was specified.*

The server program have no problem. It (maybe) disconnect successfully.

I guess my bad response to disconnection causes the client program to send packets to closed socket but I'm not sure.

What I tried to do is:

- Replace DisconnectAsync method to Disconnect method both in the server side and the client side.
- Replace DisconnectAsync method to Shutdown method in the server side.
- Remove DisconnectAsync method and make it directly close the socket in the server side.

Every approach doesn't make sense. I think I googled a lot but I can't find any answer to solve it. Could you tell me how should I use and handle Socket's Disconnect method both in server side and client side? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Sounds like you tried to send or receive after disconnecting?

Comment: _"However, after that, the client program throws an exception "_ - why are you trying to send or receive data after the disconnection? That's what doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I didn't try to send or receive data. Every other tasks will be canceled when disconnecting method is called so there's only the excuting code I post here.

Comment: @STK the error message says you did

Comment: Perhaps cancellation of the other tasks isn't completing before you disconnect.

Comment: @user253751 Sorry. You are right. After I heard that from you, I tried to make every data-sendable codes as comment, and the problem is solved. So the uncancelled tasks would be a problem. Thanks!

Comment: For a graceful shutdown, both client & server should signal an EOF via `.Shutdown(Send)`, then both should read until EOF, then `.Close`. For everything else an exception will be thrown.